# Unity 3d not working after Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

unity 2d is working fine, but nothing is displayed( except wallpaper) using unity 3d.
I have tried unity --reset, but it indicated :
unity-panel services : no such process

I have already purges and reinstalled unity-services.

Also I have checked the Unity plugin option in ccsm, but it goes 'uncheck' after every restart.

Answer (score 0):

Happening with me as well. Using Docky (which is working just fine) I can get to any application and it all works fine. Screenlets don't start. I got into software center and synaptic but couldn't identify anything I had updated that looked off. I am using 2D right now. All versions of Gnome work too.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. You should have posted this as a comment instead.